# Why does my hash have the same key mapped to multiple values?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a hash that maps an array of integers to an integer. For some reason the hash has one key mapped to multiple values like:

```
{[1,2]=>3, [1,2]=> 4}
```

How can I prevent this from happening? Running

```
for key, value in map
    puts key.inspect + "=>" + value.inspect + ":" + key.hash.inspect
end
```

gives me

```
[1, 2]=>11:11
[0, 4, 6, 8, 9]=>10:253
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]=>15:11189
[0, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]=>13:981
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]=>14:11189
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]=>12:4661
```

Comment: It shouldn't be possible to create a hash with multiple keys that are equal. Post your code, or show us how to create that hash.

Comment: I'm working on getting a way to reproduce this.  I'm having trouble reproducing it because it happens in a complicated bit of code and this isn't something that should be possible from what I understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of two cases. The first has the obscure `compare_by_identity` switched on. Don't know what to do about it. Don't switch it on? Copy everything to a normal hash?

```
h={}
h.compare_by_identity
h[[1,2]]=2
h[[1,2]]=3
p h #=> {[1, 2]=>2, [1, 2]=>3}
```

The second case is more plausible: the key gets changed after being put in the hash.

```
h={}
h[[1,2,3]]=2
h[[1,2]]=3
h.keys.first.pop # assuming ruby 1.9
p h #=> {[1, 2]=>2, [1, 2]=>3}
```

That's easy to remedy (but also easy to forget):

```
h.rehash
p h #=> {[1, 2]=>3}
```

Comment: That second case is very nasty.

Comment: Nice find on the second problem :) I suggest to simply fix the code that modifies the key instead of `rehash`ing.

Comment: Rehashing seemed to fix the problem, however there are other issues so I'm just going to rewrite the method.  Thanks for the help though.